# How to make my footer always stay at the bottom of the page, even when the page content is smaller than the screen?

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

I haven't added content to my page yet, since I'm still working on the header and footer. I noticed that my footer, instead of being at the bottom of the page, like it would be if the page was taller, it's in the middle of the page, right below the header.

I know this is what should happen in CSS, but how do I make it go to the bottom? I try `position: fixed; bottom: 0px;`, but it goes to the bottom, and when I add more content, it will either overlap or go under the content.

**Edit:** I need the footer to be adjustable height. In other words, I can't use `height: 100px;` or whatever. Also, I don't want the footer to stick to the bottom of the screen if the content is larger than the page size. If the screen height is 720px, and the page is 1200px, the footer shouldn't be at the bottom of the screen. It should be at the bottom of the page, out of view.

How can I fix this problem? I'd like to **without using JavaScript**.

Here is my current page. My footer is not a fixed height, and I can't use solutions that require that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body
            {
                font-family: Lato;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                width: 100%;
            }
            header
            {
                height: 80px;
                padding-left: 20px;
                padding-right: 5px;
                padding-top: 15px;
            }
            header h1
            {
                display: inline;
            }
            header nav
            {
                float: right;
                font-size: 18pt;
            }
            header nav a
            {
                color: #999;
                line-height: 50px;
                margin-right: 20px;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            header nav a:hover
            {
                color: #666;
            }
            header nav a.currentPage
            {
                color: #7a7acc;
            }
            header nav a.currentPage:hover
            {
                color: #7a7acc;
            }
            footer
            {
                background-color: #f2f2f2;
                color: #666;
                font-size: 12pt;
                padding: 20px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            footer div
            {
                max-width: 750px;
                margin: 0px auto;
            }
            footer a
            {
                color: #666;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>
                <img src="logo.png" />
            </h1>
            <nav>
                <a href="/" class="currentPage">Home</a>
                <a href="/services">Services</a>
                <a href="/news">News</a>
                <a href="/about">About</a>
                <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <footer>
            <div>
                <p>Footer text. Footer text. Footer text.</p>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you search google with 'sticky footer'?

Comment: I had found some things, like this: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page - But it requires that my footer has a fixed height. Pretty much every other article I found is the same. I need it to be adjustable.

Comment: That's the kind of stuff you should include in your question

Comment: I just edited the question.

Comment: +1 now that's a much better question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use css tables:

**[FIDDLE1](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/sX9Nk/)** - little content

**[FIDDLE2](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/sX9Nk/3/)** - little content + large footer

**[FIDDLE3](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/sX9Nk/4/)** - lots of content

### Markup

```
<header class="row">header content</header>
<div class="row">content here</div>
<footer class="row">footer content</footer>
```

### CSS

```
html {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    }
body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    margin:0 auto;
    }
.row {
    display:table-row;
    background:orange
}
div.row {
    height:100%;
    background:pink
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but using the `display: table-row;` kind of messed up my layout. Is there anything else I could do?

Comment: Hard to tell, without knowing your current markup and what got messed up, but how about an extra wrap div to hold your current content

Comment: @PhoenixLogan - this is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/sX9Nk/5/ - what's the problem?

Comment: It's pretty much that the margins and padding don't work inside the table anymore.

Comment: Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/e42vh/2/ as far as margin and padding go - just add them in as you need

Comment: I tried this, and there's one small problem. The `padding-left` and `padding-top` didn't work in the header. I moved the `padding-left: 20px` to the `header h1`, and it worked. When I tried to move the `padding-top: 15px`, that doesn't work. How can I have that 15px padding at the top?

Answer (score 1):

this is because your content has nothing so footer will go up.

Here I have solution
If your structure is like this

HTML

```
<header> header content goes here    </header>
<div class="container"> main content </div>
<footer> footer part </footer>
```

CSS

```
header { // header definitions  }
.container { 
       min-height: 500px;
       // other definitions  
}
footer { // footer definitions  }
```

This will stick your footer below `500px` of content even if content is empty.

Comment: That is an interesting solution, but I can't be sure how large the screen will be when my page is being viewed.

Comment: you can set this height according average screen size, as i use 600px in my sites every time. I found that's perfect. Screen size changes with every user from 480 to 1280, for which one you will set? so another solution for this is `Javascript` otherwise this is best.

Comment: Yeah, but what about HD TVs? I sometimes put things on them with an HDMI cable, including websites. My content is probably going to be shorter than an HD TV in fact.

Comment: for average resolutions use css, and check if resolution is above our definition apply JavaScript, either @Danield solution is not bad

Answer (score 1):

## You can use [flexbox auto margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins)

**Minimal Example:**

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  min-height: 100vh; /* have the flex container at least take up the viewport */
  
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}

footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  background: #999999;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>Header</header>
  <div>Some random content</div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

---

**Using the same minimal example above but with long content:**

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  min-height: 100vh; /* have the flex container at least take up the viewport */
  
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}

div {
  height: 3000px;
}

footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  background: #999999;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>Header</header>
  <div>Some random content</div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

**Using the OP's code:**

```css
body {
  font-family: Lato;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header {
  height: 80px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

header h1 {
  display: inline;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
  font-size: 18pt;
}

header nav a {
  color: #999;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header nav a:hover {
  color: #666;
}

header nav a.currentPage {
  color: #7a7acc;
}

header nav a.currentPage:hover {
  color: #7a7acc;
}

footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

footer div {
  max-width: 750px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

footer a {
  color: #666;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>
      <img src="logo.png" />
    </h1>
    <nav>
      <a href="/" class="currentPage">Home</a>
      <a href="/services">Services</a>
      <a href="/news">News</a>
      <a href="/about">About</a>
      <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <footer>
    <div>
      <p>Footer text. Footer text. Footer text.</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few weeks ago with the website I am working on and after a little bit of searching and trial and error work I managed to find the resolution to this problem.

I have here the code as it is a little bit hard to explain:

**HTML:**

```
<header>
    some header<br />
</header>
<section>
    <!-- no content -->

    <!-- little content -->
    <div id="little-content">some content</div>
    <!-- a lot of content -->
    <div id="lotsa-content">some more<br />and more<br />and more<br />and more<br />and more<br />and more<br />and more<br />and more<br />and more<br />and more<br />and more<br />and more<br />and more<br />and more<br />and more<br />and more<br />and more<br />and more<br />and more<br />and more<br />and more<br />and more<br />and more<br />and more<br />and more<br />and more content</div>
</section>
<footer>
    &copy; some footer
</footer>
```

**CSS:**

```
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

header,
footer {
    background: red;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

section {
    margin: 1.3em 0;
}

#little-content {
    display: none;
}

#lotsa-content {
    display: none;
}

footer {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Here is a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5cwsR/1/)** I made for you.

I hope this helps.

**EDIT1:**

To be more specific in answering your question: you have to make **position** the parent of the footer (that I guess it's the body) **absolute** and give it a **min-height** of **100%** (also for its **width**), the same positioning for the footer (**position: absolute;**) and also to stick it to the bottom with **bottom: 0;** and the last thing is to give a *bottom* **margin** of the footers **height** so that it doesn't overlap (I also gave a top margin due the fact that I made the header absolute as well).

**EDIT2:**

Here is the **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/94n5u/)** example with the code you provided.

Comment: Oh I just noticed that you said that your footer is not a fixed height.